# Spring 3 format annotations in Java SE

Tags: java, spring, formatting

Can I use **Spring 3** formatting annotations in Java SE application? 
I mean `@NumberFormat`, `@DateFormat`, or some *custom* format. I have a lot of *Model objects* and would like to extract their formatted fields in a generic way. I can't find a way to set up proper configuration for that.

Comment: What do you mean by a Java SE application? A Swing-based GUI app?

Comment: Not related to any UI actually. I need to stream formatted data through the network.

Comment: Have a look at org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService / org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean

Comment: Thx, I saw them before and checked one more time. The goal could be achieved with this solution, but for my simple scenario I chose my own annotation + converter. Will return to Spring for something more complex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be achieved using integration with Spring Conversion Services, you can take a look at  `FormattingConversionService` and `FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean` but require some code to have clear client API. For me it was too much efforts and I went with simple `@NumberFormat` annotation + converter written by myself.